# Unit testing a SharedPreferences wrapper with Mockito

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito, sharedpreferences

I've got a utility wrapper around `SharedPreferences` in Android. I want to unit test this wrapper, so I am mocking the parts that I am not testing:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
    prefs = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.class);
    editor = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.Editor.class);

    when(context.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(prefs);
    when(prefs.edit()).thenReturn(editor);
    when(editor.commit()).thenReturn(true);
}
```

My test, however, hits an NPE at the line where I get the `Editor`:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

What am I missing to make this mock work? I've seen a number of other SO answers recommending using various tools, but I would strongly prefer to avoid those for a simple set of tests if possible. If I do need to use another tool, what should I look at and how does that tool address the issue?

Comment: at first glance this looks similar to what i have done but can you post the logcat?

Comment: what is the Constructor of the System under test?

Comment: So the issue wasn't with the object under test (it turns out), but simply not mocking all the methods on the mocked object correctly. Thanks for checking on the constructor though, that would be a good starting place otherwise!

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be simply missing mocks. I forgot to share the line where the `prefs` was created, which relied on `context.getString()`. The error pointed me to the line I showed above, but it turned out the line above had the actual NPE. A simple mock for `.getString()` to return a test string worked:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
    prefs = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.class);
    editor = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.Editor.class);

    when(content.getString(anyInt())).thenReturn("test-string");
    when(context.getSharedPreferences(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(prefs);
    when(prefs.edit()).thenReturn(editor);
    when(editor.commit()).thenReturn(true);
}
```

Solution: Check that EVERY used method on the mocked objects is properly mocked too!